# How to get info of all workspaces that installed my slack app

Tags: node.js, slack, slack-api

How can I get Slack Workspace data while user installing my slack application?

My goal is to gather all Workspace ids that installed my application.

Main idea:

- User have my application installed
- Workspace ID(where application was installed) after authorization sends to some external url
- Server handless request

Can I solve this issue via this process? https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth

Comment: Sorry, but I have problems understanding what you want to do. Can you please re-phrase / elaborate?

Comment: I want to gather ids of all teams(workspaces) that installed my application via slack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every Slack team needs to run through the OAuth process to install your Slack app to their workspace. This is usually done by calling a webpage of your app that has a "Add to Slack" button and moderates the Oauth process with the Slack server.

When the OAuth process is successful your app will receive the workspace specific access token along with info about team including team ID and team domain from the Slack server. Your app should store this information, so that you can retrieve and use it later as requested.

If you only stored the access token from each Slack team, you can call [`auth.test`](https://api.slack.com/methods/auth.test) with that access token to retrieve more information about the connected Slack team including the team ID.

So in short, yes the OAuth process will help you gather that information.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Is `redirect_uri` parameter of auth request suitable for saving this data?

Comment: no, the redirect_uri is how you tell Slack which web page to redirect the user to after he completed the login process. I would advise to read the Slack documentation on [Oauth](https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth) carefully to get  a better understanding on how it works.

Comment: Thanks again for fresh ideas. Have a nice day and mood!

Comment: @Sabutobi Its pretty rude to first ask for help, mark a valid answer from someone as accepted and later post a new answer to your own question and accept that one instead. If you want to continue receiving help from people on this forum you may want to refrain from doing that in the future

Comment: Sorry. I didn't meant something bad!  My goal was to share solution. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 2):

If you didn't store them during the OAuth flow, then you cannot retrieve all existing workspaces that installed your Slack app.

As Erik said, you get the workspace information each time your app is installed, but it's your job to store that information.

Comment: I agree with that. But how to store that? Currently I have chain Slack User Interface - Slack API. How to connect external server while installing?

Comment: @Sabutobi The Slack app will automatically redirect a user to your external web page when the user clicks on install in the Slack App Directory. Also check out this documentation about the [Slack button](https://api.slack.com/docs/slack-button). You can try it out with one of my apps. Try to install "Raffle Bot" from the app directory.....

Comment: You need a server somewhere to host your Node.JS application. The redirect_url (where the user is redirected during the OAuth flow) will be on this server and this script is the good place to store the information in any storage engine you like to use with your Node.JS app (it can be Mongo, Redits, MySQL or anything else you're confortable working with).

Comment: Thanks once more for your advises. Plus few points to karma:). Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

If someone needs solution.
From slack-docs:

> It’s time to setup a Redirect URL for your app. This is the endpoint
>   for Slack to send a unique temporary code to your server during a
>   user’s installation. Your server will then send back this code, along
>   with your Client ID and Client Secret, so that we know we can trust
>   you.

So if someone installing your app that redirects to `redirect_url` of your app settings. Than if user accepted permissions:

- Slack API sent code to your server
- You have to send code back. Example with node see below:

`const request = require('request-promise');
let options = {
    method: 'POST',
    uri: 'https://slack.com/api/oauth.access',
    formData: {
        client_id: "client_id",
        client_secret: "client_secret",
        code: req.query.code
    }, json: true
};
request.post(options).then(result => { res.json(result) });`

In result variable you'll have all data for gathering.